# Change the career-development tag to career-development-deprecated

Tags: feature-request, tags

See [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98683/whats-the-rule-about-where-to-post-programming-career-questions) question.

Ideally we should be able to keep a tag, but flag it so that it can no longer be used.  Failing that, however, we should just rename this tag so that it's clear that it's an old one.

**Why?**

Because every time we migrate a career-development question to Programmers.so, we piss someone off a little bit.  It's annoying, even galling to find that what you thought was a perfectly good question has been migrated. Your first thought (unjustly, but nevertheless) is "WTF?!" It generates bad feeling.  However justified the migration, making SO users unhappy is not really in our best interest, so we should try to minimise migrations.

And because migrating the questions is fire-fighting, not problem solving: it won't do a good job of stopping people adding new career-development questions.  Neither will the message on the tag wiki, because no-one checks the description before adding the tag to their question.

Programmers all understand the word "deprecated", and the revised tag name would pop up as a suggestion when they type the old one, so they would see what was going on.

Comment: *"Because every time we migrate a career-development question to Programmers.so, we piss someone off a little bit."* What? Why? This is not what migration is for. There's absolutely nothing wrong with migrating questions.

Comment: Adding "deprecated" makes it a meta tag, and we all know [Jeff's view on meta tags](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/)

Comment: @Cody - pissing people off is certainly not what migration is for -- but it **is** a side-effect.  You post what you think (wrongly) is a perfectly reasonable question, and then find that someone else has (correctly) migrated it.  But your first thought is nevertheless "WTF!? What bastard did that?" Your second thought is probably more rational, but the fact remains that it's at the very least annoying.  And we should be trying to avoid annoying each other if we can.

Comment: @ChrisF - "deprecated" as a tag on it's own would be a meta-tag.  I'm not suggesting that.

Comment: I think that [your reworking of the Tag Wiki excerpt](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/career-development/info), indicating that `[career-development]` questions are off-topic, is sufficient.  However, if this is to be a `[feature-request]`, I think it should apply to all deprecated tags, and not just this one.

Comment: @Robert - 1) the reworking of the tag wiki is not enough because no-one looks at that before adding a tag to a question.  2) I agree, all deprecated tags.  But for simplicities' sake, lets limit the discussion to this one?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a "tag warning" ([tag-warnings](/questions/tagged/tag-warnings)) instead of changing the tag name.